# problems upgrading to Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: upgrade

I upgraded to 21.04 from 20.10 & got a message that says "oh no, something has gone wrong. A problem has occurred & the system can't recover. Log out & try again." I did as instructed but my system is on the loop saying the same thing. Canonical has issued a statement acknowledging the fact that the first upgrade release has a bug & they have fixed that & it is true because I upgraded another system & it is working fine.

The problem is what can I do to save my first system?

Thank you

Comment: I don't know what Canonical statement you're referring to, but I have the feeling it's one of the *shim* issues that cause a system to fail to boot and don't see how it relates. Had you added any GNOME extensions to your system? (where problem is detected & GNOME drops you out)